# Correct way to share one query result throughout the app

Tags: reactjs, redux, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

Let's say at the top of the app, we retrieve some basic information about the app or user before rendering the rest of the application:

```
const getUser = gql`
  query getUser(id: Int!) {
    user(id: $id) {
      id
      name
    }
  }
`)

function App({ data }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {!data.loading && !data.error && (
        // the application
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default graphql(getUser, {
  options: (props) => ({ variables: { id: props.id }})
})(App)
```

Now anywhere in the application, it is safe to assume that the user has been loaded and is stored. What is the proper way for another deeply nested component to the retrieve the user data without having to redo the querying and loading logic?

Answer (score 0):

This is the very basic use of a store-based library like Redux. This is not the purpose to guide every step of the way here but you are looking for a single source of truth as described here: http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.html

**In short:**
Receiving getUser response should trigger a 'LOGGED_IN' **action** dispatching user Data, this would be catched by a **reducer** updating the user object in your store (as much nested as you want), a container would then connect to this user in the store and have all its data using **connect()**

Comment: Apollo does all that for you and stores all the data in its own redux store. Using Apollo, where would you recommend as the best place to dispatch your own separate LOAD_USER action?

Comment: I agree that using Apollo is a very good way to solve the problem if you want a frontend GraphQL client. you should dispatch LOAD_USER on mutation success: this.props.mutate({ ... }).then(({ data }) => dispatch action to update store

Answer (score 0):

As of now, I'm not certain there is a proper way, but these are the options I think are reasonable

1. Manually pass down data via props
2. Wrap your deeply nested component with the same query

Manual pass down ensures your components rerender correctly, but it can be a pain to refactor. Wrapping your nested component would just hit the cache. Yes, you probably need to redo the loading logic, but that's not a show stopper.

My advice is to manually pass down props for shallow nested components and rewrap deeply nested components. Unfortunately, react-apollo doesn't provide a convenient way to access the apollo-store for nested components the same way that redux's `connect` container does.